# Do we have a RopeJoint in JBox2d?

Tags: java, android, box2d, jbox2d

Just a quick question, seems that RopeJoint is missing from jbox2d... is it really so or did they rename it to something?

Distance joint works fine, but I want to it be flexible, like a rope, not a metal rod. :)

```
    DistanceJointDef jointDef = new DistanceJointDef();

    jointDef.initialize(body1, body2, new Vec2(0,0) , new Vec2(0,-10) );

    jointDef.collideConnected = true;
    getWorld().createJoint(jointDef);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It's unsupported](http://code.google.com/searchframe#bxk7uDy-ONM/trunk/jbox2d-serialization/src/main/java/org/jbox2d/serialization/pb/PbDeserializer.java&q=ROPE%20package%3ahttp://jbox2d%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=397) afaik.

Comment: I haven't tried the alternative, libgdx, but I think that it wraps the c library impl. of [rope joint](http://libgdx.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/joints/RopeJoint.java) with JINI in their box2d version.

Comment: Seems that [jbox2d version 2.2.1.1](https://code.google.com/p/jbox2d/source/browse/?r=639#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fjbox2d-library%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Forg%2Fjbox2d%2Fdynamics%2Fjoints) includes RopeJoint, but it seems slightly incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

RopeJoint does exist now in [RopeJointDef.java](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/extensions/gdx-box2d/gdx-box2d/src/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/joints/RopeJointDef.java).